# Starting another activity after purchasing

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase

I'm new to android. 
I made a project with a buy button and trying to intent the same button to another activity, but I don't know how to do that?

Comment: post your code what you have tired

Comment: place an if -else condition inside onclicklistener , and make conditions as required